# how to keep on running the chronometer between switching the pages

Tags: android

I have two pages.First page having chronometer.it works well.but when i go to second page and come back to the first page the timer has stopped working.Can any one help me to fix this issue. Thanks..

Comment: Chronometer chrono = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
  chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
  chrono.start();

Comment: Hi Thibault thanks for your reply.I'm new to android and i don't have idea to proceed further. Also don't have any other coding can you help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your chronometer has to run in a service, so you won't lose it when you switch activities. Also, it will be hard to help you if you don't show any code.

Comment: Yeah, but we need more context. Is this code located in an activity? In a service?

Comment: Try something like: the first time you start the timer, store the current elapsedRealtime in a shared preference. When your activity restarts, start your timer from that shared value.